# Abram's worship of El Elyon

Tags: avodah-zarah, pentateuch-chumash, abraham

In Genesis 14:18-20 Abram recognizes the deity El Elyon of the Jebusite monarch Melchizedek.

Some scholars have investigated into the meaning of this name El Elyon and propose that it actually consists of two separate names of two deities. **El being the son of Elyon.**

According to Marvin Pope in his book "El in the Ugaritic texts".

Philo of Byblos identifies Elyon as being a separate deity who is the grandfather of the Ugaritic god El. He then goes on to compare Elyon to the 13th century BCE Hittite god Alalu.

https://books.google.com/books?id=ns4UAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=elyon+in+ugarit&source=bl&ots=TNQkXWyGMW&sig=RlsjOctbw4rwdwkBQpsOzSpeQ4g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=goU4VZy0BcPAsAWEsIDADQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=elyon&f=false

Lastly, there is an Aramaic inscription known as the Sefire stele from 750 BCE that also uses the term El Elyon.

According to John Day:

The inscriptions may, under one possible interpretation, **record the names of El and Elyon, "God, God Most High" possibly providing prima facie evidence for a distinction between the two deities first worshipped by the Jebusites** in Jerusalem, and then elsewhere throughout the ancient Levant.

If this is indeed the case would that mean that Abram actually proclaimed his allegiance to numerous deities by accepting a blessing in the name of El (son of) Elyon?

Comment: א–ל עליון is a name for G-d which is also used in post-biblical Jewish prayer, namely, the first blessing of the 'Amidah.

Comment: "If this is indeed the case would that mean that Abram actually proclaimed his allegiance to numerous deities by accepting a blessing in the name of El (son of) Elyon?" Yes.

Comment: Thisdoes not seem to be a Judaism question. "*If this is the case*" actually means that it is not the case so the premise is wrong.

Comment: @sabbahillel that  a totally bogus argument and it is unfortunate IMHO opinion that a new user be subjected to not just having his question closed, but to poor reasoning as well. One of the flaws  with your claim is that is it conflates an incorrect premise with an off topic question. It appears that the OP has presented evidence, and others, rather than studying and responding the Torah's view in light of  the evidence, instead hide from it, and delete it. What a shame.

Comment: Whether this question is on topic or not, it is certainly _not_ a question of comparative religion.

Comment: @Scherwin Balk I have removed the details of the non-Torah approaches to the identity of El Elyon in your question and asked for the Torah view. You can reverse the change if you wish.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok i rolled back your edits because i thought your edit was far too much and completely removed his actual question.

Comment: i think this question is valid. If Rashi, Ibn Ezra, and many other commentators can use other languages to find meanings of words, then it's fair game to look at other religions that have the same names for God as us, and see what they have to say about it, especially when Judaism doesn't really know what Elyon means in this context, plus it seems like juxtaposing it next to the tetragrammaton in exodus 12:22 may be a scribal error:

Comment: @Aaron "If Rashi, Ibn Ezra, and many other commentators can use other languages to find meanings of words, then it's fair game to look at other religions that have the same names for God as us, and see what they have to say about it" That doesn't follow.

Comment: @Aaron "i think this question is valid" I don't know what that means, as "validity [of a question]" is not a metric used on this site for any purpose that I know of.

Comment: @Aaron "Judaism doesn't really know what Elyon means in this context" On what basis would you claim that? The current answer disagrees.

Comment: @Aaron Neither "Elyon" nor the tetragrammaton appear in [Exodus 12:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm#22)

Comment: "In this verse the name of God also occurs in apposition to Ēl ʿElyōn in the Masoretic text but is absent in the Samaritan version, in the Septuagint translation, and in Symmachus." Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elyon#The_compound_.C4.92l_.CA.BFEly.C5.8Dn

Comment: @DoubleAA *Genesis 12:22 sorry about that. i think it's a valid Jewish question as it's very likely Abraham's understanding of El Elyon could come from a pre-existing idea of God that existed where he was, and this doesn't have to invalidate anything, but only can add to our knowledge of our forefather.

Comment: @DoubleAA Unless we are going to say it doesn't matter who Abraham was, it only matters who he say he was. If that's the stance people want to take, you can't exactly approach that logically/rationally.

Comment: @Aaron There is no Gen 12:22

Comment: @Aaron What makes something a "valid" jewish question vs a not "invalid" jewish question? You are still using terms that are completely meaningless here to make some point which is possibly if not likely not relevant at all.

Comment: @Aaron I don't know what your last comment has to do with anything. I think you are just ranting instead of discussing this question. What does ability to approach something logically/rationally, however we quantify that, have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

Elyon means most high.
Keil means G-d (Keil is a more appropriate way of referring to E-il without being in vain).

[This article](http://www.mayim.org.il/?parasha=%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5) discusses the meaning of Keil Elyon, konei shomayim vo'oretz.

He first brings the Gemoro in Nedarim 32b:

> R. Zechariah said on R. Ishmael's authority: The Holy One, blessed be
>   He, intended to bring forth the priesthood from Shem, as it is
>   written, And he [sc. Melchizedek] was the priest of the most high God.
>   (*translation of El Elyon*).  But because he gave precedence in his
>   blessing to Abraham over God, He brought it forth from Abraham; as it
>   is written, And he blessed him and said. Blessed be Abram (*first*) of
>   the most high God (*second*), possessor of heaven and earth, and
>   blessed be the most high God.  Said Abraham to him, 'Is the blessing
>   of a servant to be given precedence over that of his master?'
>   Straightway it [the priesthood] was given to Abraham, as it is
>   written, The Lord said unto my Lord,  Sit thou at my right hand, until
>   I make thine enemies thy footstool;  which is followed by, The Lord
>   hath sworn, and will not repent, Thou art a priest for ever, after the
>   order of Melchizedek,'  meaning, 'because of the words of
>   Melchizedek.'  Hence it is written, And he was a priest of the most
>   High God, [implying that] he was a priest, but not his seed.

It is clear from the Gemoro that El Elyon is identical with the true G-d.

Comment: Welcome to the site Moish. Thanks for the answer. The OP (original poster) seems to have evidence that the words mean something else. Accordingly, a good way to improve this answer would be to edit in evidence that his assumptions about the meanings of the words are incorrect.

Comment: Where is your source that Elyon means most high?

Comment: The answer is better now. The only problem remaining with the answer is that the Talmud was written many centuries after the Torah. Internal evidence from scripture would be more compelling.

Comment: @Aaron Gen 40:17 implies as much. Sam 2:22:14 too. Or at least something similar to high/above/atop. Other verses use it as a direction, like Chron 2:32:30.

Comment: @DoubleAA It may very well, but it also implies that it is the highest of the others shelves, meaning that Elyon should be translated as most high of others. But while we say it means most high, we negate that it's supposed to be in comparison to other related things.

Comment: @DoubleAA i think what i meant to say is what is your source that it means God most high, rather than most high of gods.

Comment: @Aaron Just because "above" in one context refers to a specific other object, doesn't meant the word necessitates other actual objects. It could be used metaphorically for instance, like how "up" is used in Deu 28:13.

Comment: @Aaron Context. Hebrew often doesn't have explicit helping verbs. The context is monotheism and the word fits just fine. There is no question unless you want to go cause problems. It doesn't say עליון מאלים for instance, and in Num 24:16 אל and עליון are paralleled, supporting the read further that both are straight nouns.

Comment: @DoubleAA i think you're being a little dishonest. It doesn't have explicit helping verbs, the context is not necessarily monotheism. It doesn't need to say עליון מאלים. The verse you quoted in Gen 40:17 says וּבַסַּל הָעֶלְיוֹן. It says in THE basket, singular, but it implies it's the highest of the other baskets. It is not implying that it happens to be a basket that happens to be on a high plane.

Comment: @DoubleAA And your comparison to Numbers is a bit more helpful, but it's still hundreds of years after Abraham existed, and people's perceptions of God could have changed by then. i'm a firm believer in monotheism with no other existential Gods, but i'm not convinced that Abraham was necessarily of the same opinion. But i'm keeping an open mind, if someone can bring real evidence.